# Function return formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple ATM simulation exercise - Need to return some information including strings and integers however return is spitting out the whole line of code, not just the string and integers combined.

#### CASHPOINT CODE

```
from SimpleCashPoint_v2 import cashpoint


print('\nTEST-EXAMPLE 1')

result = cashpoint('1234',3415.55)
print('\n---------\nRESULT:', result)
print('-' * 40, '\n')
```

#### cahspoint function code (in file `SimpleCashPoint_v2`)

```
elif trans_type == '2' : 
    withdraw = float(input('Amount to withdraw: '))
    result = ('\nYou have withdrawn ', withdraw, ' your remaining balance is ', (balance-withdraw),'£')

    return result
```

### #I expect an output of:

```
In[36]result

Out[36] You have withdrawn 10 your remaining balance is 50 £
```

#### I get an output of

```
In[36]result

Out[36]: ('\nYou have withdrawn ', 10, ' your remaining balance is ', 50, '£')
```

Comment: looks like you're returning a tuple instead of a string, try removing the brackets around `result = ('\nYou have withdrawn ', withdraw, ' your remaining balance is ', (balance-withdraw),'£') `

Comment: @Dan, while I agree that the OP is returning a tuple, removing the parentheses won't change that. `x = (a,b)` has the same effect as `x = a,b`

Comment: @Kevin good point, better to use another form of string interpolation then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace:

```
result = ('\nYou have withdrawn ', withdraw, ' your remaining balance is ', (balance-withdraw),'£')
```

with:

```
result = "\nYou have withdrawn {} your remaining balance is {} £".format(withdraw, balance-withdraw)
```

Have a search for string formatting, e.g. https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

Comment: thanks, was following an example from some old lecture notes as trying to re learn for a project and was making no sense

Answer (score 0):

You're making a tuple when you made result.

```
type(result)
<class 'tuple'>
```

So I think if you combine your elements into a single string, it would work.

One very naive way would be the following:

```
withdraw = ...
result = "/nYou have withdrawn" + str(withdraw) + "your remaining balnce is" + str(balance-withdraw) + "$"
return result
```